# How can I statically instantiate a member that depends on an instance method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static, static-members

There is base class `A` which has a method to load a data source.
Various classes are derived from `A` including derived class `B`.

Now I need to have a static member variable in class `B` e.g. `mStaticOfB` that is instantiated **only once** for `ALL` instances of class `B` to use.

The caveat here is that to instantiate the static `mStaticOfB` I need to use the data source inherited by base class `A`.But I need an instance of an object to get that and I don't have it at that point.

How can I get arround this problem? Is there a good/standard way to handle this?The only idea that I came up (and trying not to use) is to make
class B a singleton.

Comment: From your description, I don't see how making class B a singleton would solve the problem. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Ted Hopp:I would not have the member variable as `static` and by using a singleton that variable would be the same for all instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Nishant said, except threadsafe:

```
private static FieldType mStaticOfB;
...
public B(..) {
   super();
   synchronized(B.class) {
      if (mStaticOfB == null) {
         //code to set mStaticOfB
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could just have class B with unitialized static mStaticOfB, that gets initialized iff `mStaticOfB` the time when the first time the constructor is called.

```
private static FieldType mStaticOfB;
...
public B(..){

   if(mStaticOfB==null){
      //code to set   mStaticOfB
   }
}
```